# limit urls that can ask for json

Tags: php, json, security, jquery

How can I set a header, so that only the urls that I enter in an array (for instance) have access to, and can post jsonp data to my webservice in php, to prevent that random sites pass data to my service as a user.

calls made like

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  url: jsonpurl,
  jsonpCallback: "JSONCallback",
  data: {title:$("#txtTitle").val(), url:taburl},
  success: function(data, textStatus) {
    if(data.code > 0)
        {
        $("#icon").removeClass().addClass('accept');
        }
    else
        {
        $("#icon").removeClass().addClass('error');
        }
  },
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     alert("XMLHttpRequest="+xhr.responseText+"\ntextStatus="+textStatus+"\nerrorThrown="+errorThrown);
    $("#icon").removeClass().addClass('error');
  }
});
```

or

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: {title:$("#txtTitle").val(), url:encodeURIComponent(taburl)},
  success: function(data, textStatus) {
        if(data.code > 0)
    {
    $("#icon").removeClass().addClass('accept');
    }
    else
    {
    $("#icon").removeClass().addClass('error');
    }
  },
  error: function(data, textStatus) {
      alert(textStatus);
    $("#icon").removeClass().addClass('error');
  }
});
```

The reason there's both post and get is that chrome and safari extensions work fine cross-domain without having to set datatype to jsonp, but firefox doesn't.

**Update**
I know have two downvoted answers - so which do I choose?

Comment: Post using what method? Needs more info.

Comment: You're not making much sense. Urls don't post jsonp.

Comment: And you didn't clearly explain who you want to protect, your server, or the legitimate user. And against whom. And user? or rogue websites the user opens at the same time as yours? Or what?

Comment: I still don't really understand what you're doing. But limiting the urls is most likely not the answer.

Comment: what - where did my edit go!!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost a year later but anyway...

If the URLs you want to allow are on the same website, you can create a token (a random string) and store it in the session then use it on your JS requests.

Something like this :

```
function generateToken($length = 10)
{
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

// Before outputing the javascript
if(empty($_SESSION['token']) $_SESSION['token'] = generateToken();
```

Then you use $_SESSION['token'] in your ajax calls passing it in GET or POST and then before delivering the service in PHP, test if the provided token coming from JS is the same as the one in the SESSION. If so, you are safe to proceed.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Referer (sic) header ([`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)) to see where the JSONP request is originating, and filter based on this.

Comment: I can't think of a situation where this would be the right answer.

Comment: @CodeInChaos When you initiate a JSONP request from a web browser, the browser sets the `Referer` header to the page initiating the JSONP request. The remote server (assumed different) can then use this header to determine if it should honour the request or not, which is what the OP requested. (Note I gave this answer before the question was edited.)

Comment: @CodeInChaos please explain to me why you think my answer is wrong.

Answer (score -2):

don't know if it's possible through a header, but you could use:

```
preg_match() and SERVER[REQUEST_URI]
```

then just die if it doesn't match.